# How to run Apache module with superuser privileges?

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules, suexec

I am using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu. I have written one module in C language and integrated it into Apache server using Apache Extension tools (apxs). There is some part of my code where I am calling executable using exec function but I want to call that executable as superuser. so I want to run my module with superuser privileges but by default Apache is running as www-data user and asking for password for www-data.

Is there any way to run this module using superuser privileges?

Otherwise is there any other way to run root command in C within Apache module?

Is it possible to use suExec module for this?

Comment: Why not simply make root the owner of the called executable and also do chmod u+s on the executable? However, be careful running binaries as root when called from a web server anyone might be able to access!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to run the Apache module under a different user from the Apache server itself. But there are several strategies to workaround that limitation.

1) You can set the "[setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)" on the executable you want to run from Apache, like this:

```
chown root:root executable
chmod 06755 executable
```

Then, when you run this executable (say, with `fork` + `exec` or with `system`) from the Apache module, the executable will run from under the root user, with root permissions.

2) You can configure the [/etc/sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.16/sudoers.man.html) file in a way that will allow the www-data to run the executable in question with the root priviledges with the help of the sudo command.

3) You can have a separate process running with root priviledges and receiving commands from the Apache module with any kind of IPC/RPC.

Please note, that you should avoid using the root priviledges if it all possible since running your code under root might pose a security risk. Unless, of course, you're absolutely sure that your code won't have any bugs.