# Apache Custom Module permission issue with calling Libipset

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I'm working on an apache module that can check the libipset API to test if an IP is in a list. This is being used as a backup firewall for proxied connections.

I've managed to get everything working up until the C script calls `type = ipset_type_get(session, cmd);`. After testing, I believe the main problem is that libipset requires higher permissions. I'm not getting a permission error, just a null value. However, when I run the C script directly using apache as the user, I can get it to work when I grant sudo privileges to apache for the script.

I've tried 1 and 2 in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389138/how-to-run-apache-module-with-superuser-privileges) and they've both failed. Is there any other way to force root for the ipset API call?

Answer (score 0):

This action might need cap_net_admin.

If using systemd to control the process, you can add it like this:

```
[Service]
...
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN
```

Another approach would be to set the binary executable's capabilities.

```
setcap cap_net_admin=ep /usr/sbin/apache2
```

If using apparmour, you coould instead set up a profile for apache and include the line

```
capability net_admin,
```

in the file ( /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2 )

( see here : https://serverfault.com/questions/932410/enabling-apparmor-for-apache2-in-ubuntu-18-04 )